# Problem with pdf file opening in terminal

Tags: segmentation-fault

when i tried to open a pdf file in terminal using xpdf i get segmentation fault error.
how do I solve this?

here is the command and error message:

```
xpdf 320Lecture10.pdf 
***** MediaBox = ll:0,0 ur:612,792
***** CropBox = ll:0,0 ur:612,792
***** Rotate = 0
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: Try [this](http://linuxtricksandubuntraps.tumblr.com/post/45909461325/ubuntu-segmentation-fault-when-xpdf-is-launched).

Comment: Is there any reason you need to use xpdf? If not, try evince or okular.

Answer (score 0):

This is a reported bug on https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xpdf/+bug/1056361.

Anyway, you can try this method to solve your problem. In terminal run the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install libfreetype6-dev libmotif-dev
wget ftp://ftp.foolabs.com/pub/xpdf/xpdf-3.03.tar.gz
tar xzpf xpdf-3.03.tar.gz
cd xpdf-3.03
./configure -with-freetype2-library=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu -with-freetype2-includes=/usr/include/freetype2 -with-Xm-library=/usr/lib -with-Xm-includes=/usr/include/Xm
make
sudo make install
```

Source: http://linuxtricksandubuntraps.tumblr.com/post/45909461325/ubuntu-segmentation-fault-when-xpdf-is-launched

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer does not provide all the libraries that an average user might need to get xpdf to compile. The general way is

```
sudo apt-get build-dep xpdf
```

Also you will need to update the version of xpdf from foolabs to 3.04, or whatever their latest version is. I got a working version of xpdf after doing this.